# change the color of the number if it is equal to 1 in laravel datatable PowerGrid

Tags: laravel, livewire-powergrid

i am working with PowerGrid table, i need to create a condition to change the text color of the number if it is **"1"** in the column "send?".

[image]

```
  public function columns(): array
{
    return [


        Column::make('Invitado', 'invitado')
            ->sortable()
            ->searchable(),

        Column::make('Anticipada', 'anticipada')
            ->sortable()
            ->searchable(),

        Column::make('Whatsapp', 'whatsapp')
            ->sortable()
            ->searchable(),

        Column::make('Cantidad', 'cantidad'),
        Column::make('Estado', 'estado'),

        Column::make('Send?', 'send?'),

        Column::action('Action')
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding CSS classes to the span attribute based on the value of the column:

```
public function columns(): array
{
  return [
           ...
           ...
           Column::make('Send?', 'send?')->contentClasses([
                '1' => 'text-green-600',
                '0' => 'text-blue-600',
            ]),
           ...
   ]
}
```

for reference: https://livewire-powergrid.com/table/include-columns.html#contentclasses